Proving a Functional with Quadratic Form has 1 Critical Point
We have a functional
$$ \mathcal{L}(f,g) = \int_{a}^{b} \left( f^{2}(t) + g^{2}(t) \right) \: dt $$
I want to prove that $\mathcal{L}$ only has one minimum point, that is when $f(t)=g(t)=0$. Here is my attempt:

First, I discretize the integral to
$$ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{N} \: [f^{2}(t_{i}) + g^{2}(t_{i})] \triangle t  $$
where $\triangle t = (b-a)/N$, and $t_{i} = a + i\triangle t$.
The above can be approximated by:
$$ \hat{\mathcal{L}}(f_{0},g_{0},..., f_{N}, g_{N}) =  \sum_{i=0}^{N} \: [f^{2}(t_{i}) + g^{2}(t_{i})] \triangle t  $$
where $N > 0$. Then
$$ \hat{\mathcal{L}}_{f_{i}} = 2 f(t_{i}) \triangle t, \:\:\:  \hat{\mathcal{L}}_{g_{i}} = 2 g(t_{i}) \triangle t $$
for each $i$. Setting them equal $0$ will force each $f_{i},g_{i}=0$. And as $N$ goes to infinity, we can say that the functional $\mathcal{L}$ has only one minimum point, that is at $f=g=0$.
Is this a valid enough proof? and how can I make this more rigorous?

You directly have for a positive function $\int_I f =0 \implies f=0$ on $I$ if f is continuous. Your proof is not really rigourous it could work but it lacks solidity especially when you use limits. You only want to ensure that the limit is zero not your approximation at each step (in fact it also has to be but you don’t know it yet)

Are you working with a Lebesgue space or $C^0$?
